# Why is my KernelReg.bw negative? Isnt it supposed to be positive and what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, statsmodels

KernelReg.bw, which i guess, represents bandwidth for the kernel regression returns as negative. From my understanding, the bandwidth will also be positive. Please help to see if there is anything wrong with my codes.

As I think the problem lies with the EstimatorSettings, I have tried changing the parameters of EstimatorSettings several times. I need to have a rolling window of 63 for a large sample size of around 5,000.

```
from statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_regression import KernelReg
from statsmodels.nonparametric._kernel_base import EstimatorSettings


#reading the files
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/xxx.csv')
totalRows = len(df)
df['Time Index'] = df.index + 1
number = df['Time Index']
last = df['Last']
df.to_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/xxx.csv')



#Kernel Regression Portion
settings = EstimatorSettings(efficient=True, n_sub=63,
                             return_median=True, return_only_bw=False)
data = KernelReg(last, number, var_type='c', reg_type='lc', bw='cv_ls', 
defaults=settings)

print(data.bw)
```

Results:

```
[-4.50511471]
```